# Interfacing LTC2492/6/8 via SPI: is voltage shift needed?

Tags: adc, spi, level-shifting, logic-level

I'm a bit confused with [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/2498fg.pdf) for LTC2498. It says on page 27, section "Digital Signal Levels":

> The LTC2498’s digital interface is easy to use. Its digital
> inputs (SDI, fO, CS, and SCK in external serial clock mode)
> accept standard CMOS logic levels. Internal hysteresis
> circuits cantolerate edge transitiontimes as slowas 100µs.
> The digital input signal range is 0.5V to VCC – 0.5V. During
> transitions, the CMOS input circuits draw dynamic current. For optimal performance, application of signals to
> the serial data interface should be reserved for the sleep
> and data output periods.
> During the conversion period, overshoot and undershoot
> of fast digital signals applied to both the serial digital
> interface and the external oscillator pin (fO) may degrade
> the converter performance

It seems really strange: 3v3 CMOS levels are Vol (0;0.5), Voh (2.4;3.3), but the text above says "The digital input signal range is 0.5V to VCC – 0.5V" (i.e. Vol is completely out of range) and "Its digital inputs ... accept standard CMOS logic levels". On demoboards [DC1011A](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/user-guides/dc1011af.pdf) used together with [DC590](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/user-guides/dc590bf.pdf) I see no shematics that shifts digital signals voltage above CMOS Vol or below Voh.

If you have experience interfacing LTC series ADCs, could you please tell if usual CMOS levels for SPI are OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"CMOS levels" doesn't always mean 0V to 3.3V range, it also includes 0V to 5V signals.

So, the LTC2498 won't output more than 5V @5.5V supply. For a 5V MCU it's plug and play.

For a 3V3 MCU, you need to wire the SPI to the 5V tolerant pins.
Otherwise, you need to change its level (resistor bridge or a level shifter.)

If your MCU does only output 3V3 signals, then the sensor won't understand it. You will also need a level shifter.

All the above implies a 5V+ supply. If you power the sensor with 3V3, then it will work with 3V3 logic

Comment: Both ADC and MCU are 3V3 powered. Thank you. I cannot get correct resuts (readout jumps in range x1.5 over time for a constant voltages on ADCIN) and searching a source of the problem. Seems it is just ADC misfunction that cannot be fixed.

Comment: @Gryphon If you have another chip, you can test it and see whether if it's a chip problem, an LTC2498 problem or a circuit layout problem. If it's the two latter ones, feel free to post a new question. It may be interesting to debug.